# If the number of properties is greater than n, return a subgraph in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This question is a direct extension of [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36658179/if-the-number-of-properties-is-greater-than-n-return-the-whole-graph-in-neo4j) I asked previously.

Say I have a graph database that looks like this:

[image]

Just like the previous question I asked, the only really interesting thing about this is that `SomeProperty` can be 'Yes' or 'No'.

In the top row, 1 of the 3 nodes have a 'Yes' for this property.

On the bottom row, there are 3 nodes have a 'Yes' for this property. The other 2 have a 'No'.

How do I write a Cypher query that returns only THE WHOLE the bottom row, by asking the question: *Do either of these disjoint subgraphs have 2 or more values for SomeProperty = 'Yes'?*

Previously, the brilliant @cybersam recommended using something like:

```
MATCH p=(:Person)-[:RELATED_TO*]->(:Person)
WHERE 2 < REDUCE(s = 0, x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x. SomeProperty = 'Yes' THEN s + 1 ELSE s END)
RETURN p;
```

...which would return the matching paths. In this case, this would return

[image]

but I am trying to generalize this to return the whole set of 5 "B" nodes.

After struggling with this, I realize that I'm trying to create the 3 node subgraph, but not return it. I'm trying to use its existence as a way to return the supergraph of my match, and ignore any non-connected subgraphs! This is getting pretty complicated and I'm stumped.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE (albert:person {gender: 'Male', name: 'Albert', SomeProperty: 'Yes'})
CREATE (annie:person {gender: 'Female', name: 'Annie', SomeProperty: 'No'})
CREATE (adrian:person {gender: 'Female', name: 'Adrian', SomeProperty: 'No'})

CREATE (albert)-[r1:RELATED_TO]->(annie)
SET r1.relationship='related'
CREATE (annie)-[r2:RELATED_TO]->(adrian)
SET r2.relationship='related'

CREATE (bill:person {gender: 'Male', name: 'Bill', SomeProperty: 'Yes'})
CREATE (barb:person {gender: 'Female', name: 'Barb', SomeProperty: 'Yes'})
CREATE (barry:person {gender: 'Male', name: 'Barry', SomeProperty: 'Yes'})
CREATE (bart:person {gender: 'Male', name: 'Bart', SomeProperty: 'No'})
CREATE (bartholemu:person {gender: 'Male', name: 'Bartholemu', SomeProperty: 'No'})

CREATE (bill)-[r4:RELATED_TO]->(barb)
SET r4.relationship='related'
CREATE (barb)-[r5:RELATED_TO]->(barry)
SET r5.relationship='related'
CREATE (barry)-[r6:RELATED_TO]->(bart)
SET r6.relationship='related'
CREATE (bart)-[r7:RELATED_TO]->(bartholemu)
SET r7.relationship='related'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will filter out all sub-paths from the results:

```
MATCH p=(a:person)-[:RELATED_TO*]->(b:person)
WHERE
  NOT ()-[:RELATED_TO]->(a) AND
  NOT (b)-[:RELATED_TO]->() AND
  2 < REDUCE(s = 0, x IN NODES(p) | CASE WHEN x. SomeProperty = 'Yes' THEN s + 1 ELSE s END)
RETURN p;
```

Explanation:

- `NOT ()-[:RELATED_TO]->(a)` is true if the `a` node is not the at the end of a `RELATED_TO` relationship.
- `NOT (b)-[:RELATED_TO]->()` is true if the `b` node is not at the start of a `RELATED_TO` relationship.

Therefore, a matching path cannot be a sub-path.

Comment: What does the `*` character in `[:RELATED_TO*]` do?

Comment: The `*` in a relationship indicates a [variable length](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/introduction-pattern.html#_variable_length) relationship.

Comment: ah...I get it. It means "match any paths of any length, with respect to the RELATED_TO relationship." Thanks!

Comment: `[:RELATED_TO*]` is equivalent to `:RELATED_TO*1..]`. In other words, by default a variable length relationship must have a length of at least 1 (not "any length"). You should read [the documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/introduction-pattern.html#_variable_length) to understand more about how to use variable length relationships.

Comment: I have to be honest. Your answer works perfectly but I can't understand how it works. From what I read, the pseudocode is:
1) Match everything as a path which is one relationship away (?)
2) Ignore everything that is related to all nodes (??)  
3) Keep based on `SomeProperty`
I can't really figure this out! I've been at it all day :(

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully the extra info will help.

Comment: I notice the query works the same even if the two NOT statements are omitted? I may have just came up with a lousy example.

Comment: Using your code to generate the test data, I get different results for the 2 queries. With the `NOT` terms included, I get 1 result path (with 5 nodes). Without those terms, I get 3 paths returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109743/discussion-between-monica-heddneck-and-cybersam).