# Develop a cypher query in a procedural manner

Tags: neo4j, cypher, family-tree

I have been working with a family tree graph.

I would like to answer a simple question:

Return any family that

- has 3 or more Alzheimer identified members
- whom are deceased
- and who come from a family of mostly-left handed members (at least 50%).

I have mocked up two families, one of which satisfies the criteria, and one that doesn't (code at the end of the question).

The bigger family satisfied the criteria. The smaller family doesn't. (sidenote: I put definition nodes on each family as a convenience to tell them apart and to return only one family when a match was made).

[image]

I think I have figured out some parts of the solution, but I don't know how to glue them all together in a cohesive manner.

For example (thanks to @Tim Kuehn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778800/if-the-number-of-properties-is-greater-than-n-return-from-a-highly-connected-gr) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778800/if-the-number-of-properties-is-greater-than-n-return-from-a-highly-connected-gr)), I can find return the tree that satisfies the condition that there are the 3 people with Alzheimer's:

```
MATCH (f:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(person:Person) 
WHERE person.Diagnosis = "Alzheimers" 
WITH f, count(person) AS Count 
WHERE Count > 2 

// Then report the family members as a single collection
MATCH (a:Person)-[r1:FAMILY]-(f)
RETURN collect(DISTINCT a)
```

I can figure out how many nodes there are in total:

```
MATCH (n { family_ID: 'A' })--(x)
RETURN  count(x) as Tot
```

I can also figure out how many people are left-handed:

```
MATCH (f:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(person:Person) 
WHERE person.Handedness = 'Left' 
WITH f, count(person) AS Count
RETURN Count
```

but so far, my attempts to develop this query in some kind of procedural manner haven't worked.

I tried something along these lines:

```
MATCH (f:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(person:Person) 
WHERE person.Diagnosis = "Alzheimers" 
AND person.Handedness = "Left"
WITH f, count(person) AS Count 
WHERE Count > 2 

MATCH (a:Person)-[r1:FAMILY]-(f)
WITH a, 

MATCH (n { family_ID: 'A' })--(x)
RETURN  count(x) as Tot
```

but this is basically gibberish.  I get a syntax error, of all things.

In other query languages, it is often advisable to proceed step by step, perhaps by piping results through a series of temporary tables until the data is in the correct form. I can't seem to figure out how to do something analogous in CQL.  Maybe I don't know how to pipe results into collection? I don't know exactly where to go with this.

My code to create the database:

```
// First family:  family_ID = A.  This family has 3 members with Alzheimers who are not alive, and more than half of them are Left handed
CREATE 
    (   a:Person {name: 'a',    id:'1', Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers', `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left',  `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'}),
    ( aSP:Person {name: 'aSP',  id:'2', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers', `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left', `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'}),
    (   b:Person {name: 'b',    id:'3', Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'Normal',     `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left', `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'}),
    ( bSP:Person {name: 'bSP',  id:'4', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers', `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Right', `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'}),
    (bSib:Person {name: 'bSib', id:'5', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'MCI',        `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Left',  `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'}),
    (   c:Person {name: 'c',    id:'6', Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'MCI',        `Is Alive?`: 'No',   Handedness: 'Right', `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'}),
    (cSib:Person {name: 'cSib', id:'7', Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers',  `Is Alive?`: 'Yes', Handedness: 'Left',  `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'})

CREATE
    (a)-[:SPOUSE]->(aSP),
    (b)-[:CHILD]->(a),
    (b)-[:CHILD]->(aSP),
    (b)-[:SPOUSE]->(bSP),
    (bSib)-[:SIBLING]->(b),
    (bSib)-[:CHILD]->(aSP),
    (c)-[:CHILD]->(b),
    (c)-[:CHILD]->(bSP),
    (cSib)-[:SIBLING]->(c),
    (cSib)-[:CHILD]->(bSP)


// Second family:  family_ID = B.  This family does not meet the criteria
CREATE 
    (   a2:Person {name: 'a2',    id:'8',  Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'Alzheimers', `Is Alive?`: 'Yes',   Handedness: 'Right',  `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'}),
    ( aSP2:Person {name: 'aSP2',  id:'9',  Gender:'Female', Diagnosis: 'Normal',     `Is Alive?`: 'No',    Handedness: 'Left', `Risk Score`: 'GIRAFFE'}),
    (   b2:Person {name: 'b2',    id:'10', Gender:'Male',   Diagnosis: 'Normal',     `Is Alive?`: 'No',    Handedness: 'Left', `Risk Score`: 'PURPLE'})


CREATE 
    (a2)-[:SPOUSE]->(aSP2),
    (b2)-[:CHILD]->(a2),
    (b2)-[:CHILD]->(aSP2)


// Create the definition node for the first family:
CREATE 
    (famA:Family {family_ID:'A'}) 
    WITH famA
    MATCH (a:Person {name:"a"})-[*]-(b:Person)  
    MERGE (famA:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(a) 
    MERGE (famA:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(b)


// Create the definition node for the second family:
CREATE (famB:Family {family_ID:'B'}) 
    WITH famB
    MATCH (a2:Person {name:"a2"})-[*]-(b2:Person)  
    MERGE (famB:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(a2) 
    MERGE (famB:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(b2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the [filters](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-collection.html#functions-filter) - this is what you need:

```
MATCH (Family:Family)<-[r:FAMILY]-(Person:Person)
WITH
  Family, collect(Person) as F
WITH
  Family, size(F) as sF, F,
  filter(x in F where x.Handedness='Left') as LH,
  filter(x in F where x.Diagnosis="Alzheimers" AND x.`Is Alive?`='No') as AD
WHERE
    (size(LH) >= sF/2) AND (size(AD) >= 3)
RETURN Family, 
       F as wholeFamily,     
       extract(n IN AD | n.name) as whoAD,
       size(LH) as sLH, size(AD) as sAD
```

Comment: At first the syntax for `extract` threw me off but now I see that the `|` is more like a pipe than a bool 'or'. This is some great code...totally impressed and very thankful!

Comment: It's interesting -- first, you matched a pattern, then took some time out with a `WITH` section to do the filtering, then went back to matching the pattern in the `WHERE` clause...and in doing this, used derived values carried over from the `WITH`. Very cool.

Comment: How would I be able to return the whole family, from having determined the identity node? I tried to carry `Person` through to the end and then return it, but got errors.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck Pass and return F (collect of family persons) - see update.

Answer (score 1):

You can chain a reference through a series of filters to get the final answer. To get counts of different functions on fields, one has to repeat the query (which I find unfortunate - there should be a way to count multiple items from a single graph result).

In the following example I get a family reference based on number of Alzheimer's cases, and then use that reference through the rest of the query to count groups of people before reporting a conclusion at the end.

The end result looks like so:

```
// Find the families with 2 or more Alzheimers cases
MATCH (fam:Family)<-[:FAMILY]-(person:Person)
WHERE person.Diagnosis = "Alzheimers"
WITH fam, count(person) AS fAlzCount
WHERE fAlzCount > 2
with fam

// Count the # of left-handed family members 
MATCH (fam)-[:FAMILY]-(person:Person)
WHERE person.Handedness = 'Left' 
WITH fam, count(person) AS LeftCount

// Count the total # of  family members 
MATCH (fam)-[:FAMILY]-(person:Person)
WITH fam, LeftCount, count(person) AS AllCount

// and then filter for families where more than 1/2 are left-handed
// tofloat() is used to convert the integer results so we can test 
// against a float at the end
WHERE  tofloat(LeftCount) / tofloat(AllCount) > 0.5
RETURN fam, LeftCount, AllCount
```