# Can neomodel return a sub-graph?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neomodel

And if so how. I can see how to run cypher to return a list of nodes but I need the paths as well. I can sort of do this with two queries but surely there is a way to do this with just one?

I'm using neomodel with django and need to return a subgraph for visualisation with d3.js.

Comment: Maybe you should check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101789/extract-subgraph-in-neo4j), it seems related to your question.

Comment: Alas is doesn't as I can do what I need in neo4j, my challenge is that neomodel doesn't seem to return a path from a match, only nodes.